# How do I debug a program that runs in debug, builds and deploys without error, but then errors in UnityPlayer.dll?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, uwp, hololens, windows-mixed-reality

I'm developing a tool for Mixed Reality in Unity 2017.4, the project runs on the Hololens through remote emulation in editor and the editor itself, the project builds and deploys to both emulator and device from Visual Studio 2017. But when the program runs the UnityPlayer.dll throws one of two breakpoints, either 0x0000003 or 0x0000005. Here's my call stack:

> UnityPlayer.dll!623d51fb()  Unknown
>
> [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for UnityPlayer.dll]
>
> UnityPlayer.dll!623d5703() Unknown
>
> UnityPlayer.dll!623d58d7() Unknown
>
> UnityPlayer.dll!61b1d66d() Unknown
>
> ...
>
> UnityPlayer.dll!630b22e2() Unknown
>
> UnityPlayer.dll!630b2444() Unknown
>
> UnityPlayer.dll!630bed92() Unknown
>
> [External Code]

It also says that UnityPlayer_UAP_x86_debug_dotnet.pdb is not found when these errors are thrown and I have debugger set on mixed or native. In managed it simply throws those 2 errors, currently 0x0000005 seems to be occurring more often.

Thanks to Josh Peterson's comment here's a hopefully better callstack:

> UnityPlayer.dll!OutOfMemoryError() Unknown
>
> UnityPlayer.dll!MemoryManager::Allocate(unsigned int,unsigned int,struct MemLabelId const &,enum AllocateOptions,char const *,int) Unknown
>
> UnityPlayer.dll!MemoryManager::Reallocate(void *,unsigned int,unsigned int,struct MemLabelId const &,enum AllocateOptions,char const *,int)    Unknown
>
> UnityPlayer.dll!realloc_internal(void *,unsigned int,unsigned int,struct MemLabelId const &,enum AllocateOptions,char const *,int) Unknown
>
> UnityPlayer.dll!dynamic_array::reserve(unsigned int)  Unknown
>
> UnityPlayer.dll!DecompressSubprogramBlob() Unknown
>
> UnityPlayer.dll!Shader::Transfer >(class StreamedBinaryRead<0> &)  Unknown
>
> ...
>
> UnityPlayer.dll!Platform::Details::__abi_FunctorCapture,void,struct Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ^>::Invoke(struct Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ^)   Unknown
>
> UnityPlayer.dll!Windows::System::Threading::WorkItemHandler::[Windows::System::Threading::WorkItemHandler::__abi_IDelegate]::__abi_Windows_System_Threading_WorkItemHandler___abi_IDelegate____abi_Invoke(struct Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction ^)  Unknown
>
> threadpoolwinrt.dll!734c4c6f() Unknown
>
> [Frames below may be incorrect and/or missing, no symbols loaded for threadpoolwinrt.dll]
>
> [External Code]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I removed non-descriptive extra lines so this is slightly easier to read. I tried to capture your question as a question in the title as well, so it will hopefully be more discoverable. I also excluded tags from the new title, since these are encoded by default for search engines. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Unity does publish debugging symbols, you should be able to at least get function names from the native call stack. See this documentation for information about how to connect to the Unity symbol server: https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/WindowsDebugging.html

Answer (score 0):

Some things to check:

- In Visual Studio, try building in the Release configuration instead of Debug.
- In Unity, try changing the scripting backend in the player settings for WSA. I have had better luck with the .NET backend than the IL2CPP backend.
- Update VS2017. We had an issue with a specific version of VS2017 breaking builds (though I can't remember which one).

Comment: Done all of these now. There was a VS update I needed apparently and I've been running on .NET backend already, about to try rebuild with IL2CPP again. And I'm now running in release but getting the same issue.